# Move all .txt files into one directory

Tags: command-line, files, find, recursive, move

I have almost 6000 directories with thousands of files:

```
all/recup_dir.1/1.txt
all/recup_dir.1/2.jpg
...
all/recup_dir.5987/1.txt
all/recup_dir.5987/2.txt
...
```

and I want to move all .txt files in the all/txt folder.
I have used this command:

```
mv **/*.txt txt
```

but I get this error:

```
bash /bin/mv arg list too long
```

How can I do?

Comment: if you just move all .txt files from your example to a common folder, the ones with the same basenames (e.g., `1.txt`) will overwrite each other. How do you want to resolve this conflict?

Comment: @stefan I could rename it with 1-1.txt, 1-2.txt, 1-3.txt, ecc

Answer (score 1):

**`find`** solution:

```
find all -type f -name "*.txt" ! -path "all/txt/*" -exec echo mv -t all/txt '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this.  To avoid moving files just moved to `all/txt`, move
them to a new `txt` directory outside of `all`, then move `txt` under
`all`.  Here we go:

```
$ mkdir txt
```

The next one will only **print** all move commands.  Check that you like
what you see:

```
$ find all | sed -rn 's#^all/recup_dir.([^/]*)/([^/]*).txt$#mv -n "&" "txt/\1-\2.txt"#p'
mv -n "all/recup_dir.20/2.txt" "txt/20-2.txt"
mv -n "all/recup_dir.20/1.txt" "txt/20-1.txt"
mv -n "all/recup_dir.19/5.txt" "txt/19-5.txt"
mv -n "all/recup_dir.19/4.txt" "txt/19-4.txt"
...
```

When satisfied, run them by appending `| sh`:

```
$ find all | sed -rn 's#^all/recup_dir.([^/]*)/([^/]*).txt$#mv -n "&" "txt/\1-\2.txt"#p' | sh
```

then put `txt` where it belongs:

```
$ mv txt all
```